# cl.exe produces weird assembly code

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I compiled this C code:

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0;
    i = 0;
    i = 0;
}
```

and I got this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push ecx
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-4],0
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-4],0
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-4],0
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
retn
```

My question is why is there `push ecx`? and how come there is no `sub esp,4` or something to make space on the stack? No compiler options used.

Comment: It's just another way to adjust the stack pointer to reserve space for the local variable.  Same as sub esp,4 but requiring only a single instruction byte.  I'd guess you have space optimization enabled although the code certainly isn't optimized.  Always document compiler version and compile options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way will make 4 bytes of space available on the stack, and the `push` saves a couple of bytes over the `sub`. Maybe the compiler writer decided to optimize this case by pushing a register.

Comment: would you perhaps also know why would gcc produce in the same place sub esp,10 instead?